# Improving compile time of long combine chain

Tags: swift, xcode, compilation, combine

I have a longish list of API endpoints I need to call sequentially in a specific order to keep my app's state in sync with a server. I chose to use a Combine chain to implement this. Each operation calls a function that does some work (reads and writes some Core Data models) and returns the same type, something like: `-> AnyPublisher<SyncEvent?, Error>`

together it looks something like this:

```swift
Timer.publish(every: interval, on: .current, in: .common)
  .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
  .flatMap(syncEndpointOne)
  .flatMap(syncEndpointTwo)
  .flatMap(syncEndpointThree)
  .flatMap(syncEndpointFour)
  ...
```

After adding more than a few of these functions the Swift compiler and language server just gives up and becomes unresponsive, it will hang forever. Commenting out individual lines verifies there are no issues with each line specifically - just that this is too complicated for the compiler to infer and reason about.

How can I rewrite this or give the compiler more information to fix this?

(xcode 12.5.1 and swift 5.4.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this would eventually compile if the chain was split out into it's own function e.g:

```
func syncEndpoints(event: SyncUpdate?) -> AnyPublisher<SyncUpdate?, Error> {
  return syncEndpointOne
      .flatMap(syncEndpointTwo)
      .flatMap(syncEndpointThree)
      .flatMap(syncEndpointFour)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

And then:

```
Timer.publish(every: interval, on: .current, in: .common)
 .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
 .flatMap(syncEndpoints)
 ...
```